# Git pull a change of a gerrit project using gitpython

Tags: git, gerrit, gitpython

I am trying to pull a `change` of a `gerrit` project into my local repository using `gitpython`. This can be done using the following command,

```
git pull origin refs/changes/25/225/1
```

Here, `refs/changes/25/225/1` is the change that has not been submitted in `gerrit`. I have cloned the `gerrit` project into a directory. Now, I want to `pull` the changes that have not submitted into this directory. Below mentioned code is the usual way to `git pull` into a directory containing `.git` file.

```
#gitPull.py

import git

repo = git.Repo('/home/user/gitRepo')
o = repo.remotes.origin
o.pull()
```

Here, `gitRepo` has the `.git` folder(it is the cloned gerrit project). I did a lot of searching, but did not find a way to execute the above mentioned command `git pull origin refs/changes/25/225/1` using `gitpython`.

Comment: I am not a gitpython user, but if you start with the rule "never use pull" (to be modified to "use pull *after* you get to the point where you never *need* to use it") and break the operation into its two more elemental steps, `git fetch` and `git merge`, I will bet you will find those to be very easy to do in gitpython.

Comment: I was looking for ways to to `fetch` or `merge` in `git`. Found that could use `git.execute()` for any customized `git` function. That did the trick. Could use it for either `fetch` and then `merge` or even directly `pull`.

Answer (score 1):

well, it's a simple as giving the branch as [`refspec` parameter to the pull method](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.remote.Remote.pull) :

```
import git

repo = git.Repo('/home/user/gitRepo')
o = repo.remotes.origin
o.pull('refs/changes/25/225/1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import git
import os, os.path

g = git.Git(os.path.expanduser("/home/user/gitRepo"))
result = g.execute(["git", "pull", "origin", "refs/changes/25/225/1"])
```

Could do the same using `execute()`.